# Joomla installation fails on XAmpp

Tags: joomla, xampp, joomla3.0

Hi All when I am trying to install joomla on XAMPP server i am getting below error

[client ::1:51690] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:/C:/xampp/htdocs/Joomla30/templates/protostar/templateDetails.xml" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla30\libraries\cms\installer\installer.php on line 2195, referer: http://localhost/Joomla30/installation/index.php

Can any one help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had a similar problem with easyphp, some research led me to two problems.

The first had to do with the premise between Mysql and joomla see the php configuration file.

The second and most likely thing you have is a problem in the paths you give to joomla error log. Checks the php configuration file.

Loking in to your erro it's related to path of instaled joomla. Solution install again the joomla but be sure to save it in your created site folder for exemple www.mysite in your apache htdocs it worked for me.